# ui-select : set width in Bootstrap grid system

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, ui-select

I have a form with a ui-select in a bootstrap grid.
I want my ui-select to be as wide as the input below it.
Here is my code

```
<div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4" style="text-align:right;">Pays</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <ui-select ng-model="adresse.pays" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" ame="pays">
                <ui-select-match placeholder="Sélectionnez un pays..." allow-clear>{{$select.selected.nom}}</ui-select-match>
                <ui-select-choices repeat="pays in payss | propsFilter: {nom : $select.search}">
                    <div ng-bind-html="pays.nom | highlight: $select.search"></div>
                </ui-select-choices>
            </ui-select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label class="col-md-4" style="text-align:right;">Mail</label>
        <input type="text" class="col-md-3 input-sm"
            ng-model="adresse.mail">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label class="col-md-4" style="text-align:right;">Code adresse client</label>
        <input type="text" class="col-md-8 input-sm"
            ng-model="adresse.codeAdresseClient" name="codeAdresse">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label class="col-md-4" style="text-align:right;">Interlocuteur</label>
        <input type="text" class="col-md-3 input-sm"
            ng-model="adresse.interlocuteur" name="interlocuteur">
    </div>
</div>
```

This code produces this:
[image]

If someone knows how to do that...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion is to either

- use bootstrap theme (instead of select2), or
- simply set width to 100%

Check this plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/9mI8nO?p=preview

```
<ui-select ng-model="person.selected" theme="bootstrap">
  ...
</ui-select>

<ui-select ng-model="person.selected" theme="select2" style="width:100%">
  ...
</ui-select>
```

Comment: bootstrap theme does the fixing. :)

Comment: This is perfect! Should be the accepted answer. Thanks for the plunk

Comment: awesome! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
.ui-select-multiple input.ui-select-search {
     width: auto !important;
}
```